# In Dark Souls, What is Estus?

Tags: dark-souls

In Dark Souls, the undead can replenish their health by drinking from an Estus Flask (*an undead favourite*). I assume these are dull, green, flasks which contain something called Estus.

**What is Estus? What is the lore behind Estus? Please annotate any potential spoilers.**

Comment: Hi! I would like to know why people are downvoting the question. Thanks!

Comment: This is because it is largely a lore question, which tend to be tricky to answer.

Comment: Just because a question is difficult or "tricky" to answer, that doesn't mean it's erroneous, does it? I think the downvotes are in bad faith. I *am*, after all, still in topic, am I?

Comment: Anyway, I read about the issue in meta. I'll leave the related post here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/can-i-make-questions-about-lore-in-arqade

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Estus is essentially bottled *fire*. In the world of *Dark Souls*, fire is symbolic of life and the power thereof. The current Age, the age of gods (Gwyn, Seath, Nito, The Witch of Izalith, The Pygmy), is also known as *The Age of Fire*.

When you rest at a bonfire, you capture some of its flame in your Estus Flask. Bonfire themselves are beacons of fire, life, and humanity. This can be evidenced by kindling, strengthening bonfires by sacrificing humanity to them, as well as you regaining health whenever you rest at a bonfire. Thus, whenever you drink from your Estus Flask, you are "consuming" the life held within the flames.

Comment: This seems like conjecture...

Comment: It quite literally says in the introduction that fire is akin to life. *"Heat and cold,* ***life*** *and death"*

Comment: Conjecture or not, to anyone that has played the game for an extended period of time, this will ring true in their ears.

Comment: @Yuki That's your interpretation that heat maps to life and cold maps to death. It can quite conceivable be two different statements that are opposites, nothing explicitly states what the `Estus` is. I think it's a good answer (I upvoted), but there nowhere in the game does it definitely say what Estus is.

Comment: The intro says that with fire came disparity, i.e. distinction or inequality, and goes on to list some opposites that appeared as a consequence. "Fire is akin to life" really *is* conjecture, especially as life existed prior to the emergence of Fire, with the everlasting dragons.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat If you wanna get technical, you can't define something without also defining the opposite of it. There can not be life, but no death. The lack of death makes it impossible to define what "life" is. Fire brought disparity, it brought heat **and** cold, life **and** death, light **and** darkness. Neither of those 6 were defined before the fire.

Comment: Hey @Kevin, I disagree with your point. Life makes sense without death, but death doesn't make sense without life: something has to die, yet one could conceive of a universe where there is life and living creatures and no death. We could get carried away with this, but even in the Bible man was first granted eternal life before commiting original sin  and being made mortal as punishment.

Comment: Although it's likely, I agree that it's conjecture; however, the vast majority of lore in the Souls series is conveyed through implications and hints as opposed to outright statement of fact.

Comment: Could still use some supporting item descriptions or something.